# Web app doesn’t work on chrome for android

Tags: ionic-framework

The app works fine on my laptop. After logging in on my phone I see a blank page. The only error I get is "403 forbidden" for the `manifest.json` file. The app is deployed on an nginx server. I used `npm run ionic:build --prod --release` to build it.

I dont get the `403 forbidden` error on my laptop. The permissions for `manifest.json` are set to `-rw-------`. The directory permissions are set to `drwxr-sr-x`

Answer (score 0):

Had to `chmod 755` the `manifest.json` file